# Cannot navigate to a specific screen using FCM onBackgroundMessage

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I receive a notification when my app is killed, I want to navigate to a specific screen of my choice when I tap on the notification. I have added the code for the navigation but the app does not navigate to that screen. Instead, the app opens and navigates to the first screen.

Here's my code:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
   flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/splash',
                playSound: true
              ),
            ));

            // This does not seem to work as I am not directed to OrdersScreen 
            navigatorKey.currentState
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
}


void initState(){ 
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid  = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/splash');
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android:initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
     FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message != null) {
          navigatorKey.currentState
                       .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
      }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) version 10.0.0 or above, the below code should work.
You should call `handlePushNotification()` function in your first screen.
To save last foreground screen path, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or another solution.

This is a very basic example for your problem.

```
void handlePushNotification() {
    //FOREGROUND MESSAGES
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      _showSnackBar(message: message);
    });
    //BACKGROUND MESSAGES - ONRESUME
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
     //Detect your current screen if you wish when "onResume" called.
     if( currentScreenPath == 'FirstScreen' ){            
        _navigateSpecificScreen();
     } else {
        debugPrint('Specific screen is already foreground!');
        _showSnackBar(message: message);
     }        
    });
    //BACKGROUND MESSAGES - ONLAUNCH
    if (_firebaseMessaging != null) {
      _firebaseMessaging!.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
        if (null != message) {
          _navigateSpecificScreen();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

If your only problem is navigate to a specific screen when your app killed and relaunch, you can ignore the following.

If your application is more extensive, you should prefer to control all your navigations from a single class.

Maybe you can use `onGenerateRoute` property in `MaterialApp`.
This is an example: [how to use onGenerateRoute](https://dev.to/geekpius/how-to-use-on-generate-route-in-flutter-4kml)

You can create a function for track the which screen is foreground in your `RouteGenerator` class.
You also need to handle `Navigation.of(context).pop()`.

You don't want to navigate it again when a screen is already foreground when onResume called.

Comment: I added the getinitialmessage in my initState but I was not redirected to ordersscreen when I tapped on the notification. Please see my edited code.

Comment: Did you add "click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" property in your notification message?

Comment: Yes I have added that.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I am using awesome notification to do that. this is done inside the home screen.
I do not know if this is the best way, but it works for me perfectly.
You also can distinguish the buttons inside the notification(if there are) using `receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed`.

if the user does not press the button (or there is no button), so there is no buttonkeypressed, and I handled this in my code.

awsome notifications link: https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////// HOME SCREEN   //////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    try {
      AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((receivedNotification) {
        // print(receivedNotification.toString());
        // print(receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed.toString());
        print("I am listning");
        //////////////     REPLY  button
        if (receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed == "REPLY") {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            ReplayInterface.routeName,
          );
        }
        /////////////////  REJECT  button
        else if (receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed == "REJECT") {
          getReject();
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RegectInterface.routeName);
        }
        /////////////////  BODY Notification
        else if (receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed != "REJECT" &&
            receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed != "REPLY") {
          print(receivedNotification.buttonKeyPressed);
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Counter.routName);
        }
        /////////////////  NOT NOTIFICATION
        else {
          return;
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("e is $e");
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/");
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

`

Comment: This will be honestly be an overkill for me. All I want is to navigate to a certain screen upon tapping on the notification.

Comment: try listening to the notification inside the ` _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`  using awesome notification, and navigate as you want. I think that will be better for the performance of the app.